# How to Batch update Salesforce Sales Cloud from Marketing Cloud using SSJS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, automationstudio

We have to perform a batch update in Salesforce CRM custom object based on changes within Salesforce Marketing Cloud Data Extension.

How can we do this using SSJS?

Although Journey Builder can perform data updates, our requirement here is to update salesforce in batches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to have a cloud page with Salesforce Ampscript logic which will update salesforce data. Then use SSJS to load the cloud page which will trigger the ampscript execution.

Cons with this approach is we don't know how much API will be consumed and if it will really  scale for bulk jobs.

Another alternative is to use an data synchronization application like Skyvia.